# define a program section in C code (GCC)

Tags: gcc

In assembly language, it's easy to define a section like:

```
.section foo
```

How can this be done in C code? I want to put a piece of C code in a special section rather than `.text`, so I will be able to put that section in a special location in the linker script.

I'm using GCC.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is going to be compiler specific -- perhaps you can tell us which one you're using...

Comment: look at pragma's for your compiler

Answer (score 22):

The C standard doesn't say anything about "sections" in the sense that you mean, so you'll need to use extensions specific to your compiler.

With GCC, you will want to use the `section` attribute:

```
extern void foobar(void) __attribute__((section("bar")));
```

There is some limited documentation [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html), including a warning:

> Some file formats do not support
>   arbitrary sections so the section
>   attribute is not available on all
>   platforms. If you need to map the
>   entire contents of a module to a
>   particular section, consider using the
>   facilities of the linker instead.

Comment: thanks men/women. extern void foobar(void) __attribute__((section("bar"))); works for me.