# How do I specify output sections in C files compiled using GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, ld

In assembly language I use .section directive to tell the assembler what section to output to e.g

```
.section init
```

Is there a way to do the same in C files. I want the code for some files to go into different section so I can load it to different memory address. I know I can create a script for ld and specify sections there but I dont want to do that. Is there some compiler switch or .section directive kind of thing for C files that will do this?

Comment: Similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516398/define-a-sections-in-c-code-gcc.

Answer (score 18):

There is:

```
__attribute__((section("section_name")))
```

So, for example:

```
void foo() __attribute__((section(".text_foo")));

....

void foo() {}
```

Would place `foo` in `.text_foo`

See [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) for more information.

Comment: thanks but that is for one function only. I want some thing that will the same for complete C file

Comment: Tip: you can use a macro to make it less ugly.

Comment: A macro is a great choice, as it also helps with portability.

Comment: @binW: frankly, the best way to do that is to use a linker script. From the GCC docs: "If you need to map the entire contents of a module to a particular section, consider using the facilities of the linker instead." (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.5/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html)

Comment: I am going to use linker script but I need multiple text sections i.e .init, .text and more. To add files to specific sections i will need to name every file like foo.o(.text) and i want to avoid that. I am hoping I can do something like *(.my_section)

Comment: @binW: in the header file defining the prototypes for each function you want in each section, just add the attribute. It makes it easier to move the functions around individual C files and it also makes it easier for someone else to figure out what your intentions are by just glancing at the header.

Comment: I have the same wish. But using __attribute__ even with a macro is tiresome. Easy to forget for some static variable. And it might work without because a constant gets optimized away or suddenly break because it no longer does inline a function.

Comment: using the linker is good but i want the notion in the code! is there a way to set the entire module section by code annotation?